# How to split a list by a character and add it to a new list

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is split the elements within a list by the ";" and add it to a new list. My current code is:

```
n = []
    s = open("rankings.txt").readlines()

    for i in s:
        n[i] = s[i].split(';')[1]
```

Each element in s containts ";", so it should be able to split each one there. This is the contents of s.

```
['Team 1;12\n', 'Team 2;45\n', 'Team 3;66\n', 'Team 4;77\n', 'Team 5;8\n', 'Team 6;99\n', 'Team 7;22\n', 'Team 8;13\n', 'Team 9;46\n', 'Team 10;97\n', 'Team 11;64\n', 'Team 12;65\n', 'Team 13;32\n', 'Team 14;98\n', 'Team 15;78\n', 'Team 16;752\n', 'Team 17;72\n', 'Team 18;73\n', 'Team 19;76\n', 'Team 20;419\n', 'Team 21;48\n', 'Team 22;16\n', 'Team 23;469\n', 'Team 24;82\n', '\n']
```

I want n to contain [12, 45, 66...]

Comment: use `print(i)` to see what you have in variable - it is NOT integer which you could use as `[i]`, it is text. And empty list `n` doesn't have `n[i]` - you have to use `n.append(item)`

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you're expecting. Instead of `readlines()`, just use `open()` and run a loop, which achieves the same task, only efficiently.

```
new_list = []
f = open("rankings.txt", "r")
for x in f:
    temp = x.split(";")
    new_list.append(int(temp[1]))
```

Edited after comment to typecast to int

Comment: it will work correctly except last element on the list - empty line `'\n'`

Comment: Oh, yes.. In that case they'll have to type cast it first. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: I would `strip()` line and check if I get empty line `if x.strip():` but in other answer I see `if ";" in x:` which seems even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension.
This works on your case, you might need to modify it a bit depending on specific cases that happen to break it, if you have some input with mismatches, but it shouldn't be very difficult:

```
n = [int(x.split(';')[1]) for x in s if ';' in x]
```

where `s` is your list of strings.
Note that the if at the end is because your last item is only `'\n'` and the int ignores the `'\n'` part. These are the parts you might need to modify in different cases.
If you want me to expand what the list comprehension is/does write so in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. `for i in s` means `i` is a string from the list, not an index. Change to `for i in range(len(s))` to get integers.
2. `n` is an empty list, and does not have an `n[i]` for any non-negative `i`. Append new members by changing to `n.append(...)`.
3. There are members in `s` without `;` (the last one). Maybe add an if statement?

Or you could write this in a nice little comprehension:

```
n = [int(x.split(';')[1]) for x in s if ';' in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

below solution should work and list1 is your input list.

```
num_list = []
for ele in list1:
   ele = ele.rstrip("\n")
  if ele:
     num_list.append(ele.split(";")[1])
print (num_list)
```